# Flutter State value updates parent value (?)

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I m facing a new situation with Flutter, that I don t understand.
I have the following scenario.
Passing a post class value to a new window using await Navigator.of(context).push(
MaterialPageRoute() in order the modify the post value;
I m duplicating this value in order to have a temporary one (in case of canceled modifications)

Using setState, I update the newPost value, and I just realized it updates the original Post as well. Witch questions my understanding of state values in Flutter.

As an example :

```
class EditPost extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyPostModel post;

  EditPost({
    Key key,
    @required this.post,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context,
      {Database database, UserModel user, MyPostModel post}) async {
    //get the context form the BuildContext of parent controller
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => EditPost(
          post: post,
        ),
        fullscreenDialog: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  _EditPostState createState() => _EditPostState();
}

class _EditPostState extends State<EditPost> {

  MyPostModel newPost;

@override
  void initState() {
    newPost = widget.post;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.deepPurple)),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('modify post title')),
        body: TextButton(child(Text('tst'), onTap((){setState((){newPost.title='mod';})})),)));}
```

in the debug View, newPost.title gets the correct 'mod' value, but post.title gets changed too (to 'mod').
What Am I missing ?

Comment: *"I m duplicating this value [...]"* - where?

Comment: in initState,  newPost = widget.post;

Comment: no, it is not a duplication - you are simply assigning a reference to the existing `MyPostModel` object

Comment: like a 2way binding ? Is there a way to pass the post value to newPost in init State without having it assigned ?

Comment: you need to make a deep copy of your `MyPostModel`

Comment: would you please elaborate on how to make a deep copy ?

Comment: create a `MyPostModel` constructor that takes an original `MyPostModel` object as a parameter and copy its content field by field